# How can the RMSE of penalized regression be lower than linear regression?

Tags: machine-learning, regularization

It appears to me that linear regression is choosing a $\hat{\textbf{w}}$ in

$$E[Y] = \textbf{w}^T \textbf{x} \quad \quad (1)$$

by minimizing the least squares criterion $$\sum_{i=1}^N (y_n - \textbf{w}^T \textbf{x}_n)^2. $$ So that Linear Regression chooses the coefficients to minimize the mean squared error.

In penalized regression we are choosing a $\hat{\textbf{w}}$ as in (1) which we choose, this time, to minimize the penalized cost function

$$ \sum_{i=1}^N (y_n - \textbf{w}^T \textbf{x}_n)^2 + \sum_{d=1}^D p_\lambda(w_d).$$

My question is how can penalized regression result in a lower mse than linear regression? Given that linear regression is designed to minimize the mse.